# How can I rename my Android device?

Tags: settings

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I change the name of my Android device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/37/how-do-i-change-the-name-of-my-android-device)

It has a really long cryptic name. I want to rename it to something shorter.

Comment: Do you want to do this programmatically?

Comment: @Michael I don't think so. This guy just asked this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3664630/my-app-just-crashed-how-can-i-get-the-crash-log some minutes ago. He wants to change the name of his handset. @Sheeham I think it does not worth the effort though; you can always use copy&paste or create an alias (or direct access if you use Windows).

Comment: i just want to rename it, so i can type a shorter name into my terminal when im debugging.

Comment: You don't need to retype at all, pressing the "up button" on most Linux terminals and Windows' command prompt will give you the previous commands you have typed. Also, Copy-pasting in Linux terminal is easy, just select the text and middle click. Copy pasting in Windows' command prompt is more tricky, but doable: http://www.softwaretipsandtricks.com/windowsxp/articles/124/1/Command-Prompt--Quick-edit-mode. Alternatively, just unplug the devices/emulator you're not using. Alternatively, if you're using Eclipse, you can set which device you want to debug on.

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about when you do:

> abd -s device-serial-number command

Then you can do this if it is the only device connected via USB:

> adb -d command

But that will only work if you have just one device connected via USB, if there are more than one android devices connected via USB, it will return the "multiple devices" error.