# Change Phone name on Nexus 4

Tags: settings

When I look into the logs of my router, I have trouble identifying my own phone.

How can I change the name of my phone, on my nexus 4 running latest Android OS, **without rooting it**? Is it even possible?

Comment: Do the solutions in [How do I change the name of my Android device?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/37) work?

Comment: I forgot to mention I dont want to root it.

Comment: Why don't you identify with your phone MAC Address?

Comment: It is still not readable

Answer (score 1):

Developer options > Device Hostname should get you where you need to go. 
You may need to mash "build number" in "About phone" a few times to make the Developer Options appear in your settings app...

EDIT: Apparently that's for CyanogenMod only. Without that option, you'll need root...

Comment: I didnt find the option "Device Hostname". Im running 4.4

Comment: Do you have developer options enabled?

Comment: Yes, I do have them on

Comment: Huh, evidently that's a CM thing.