# How to change wifi device name on Android 7?

Tags: settings, 7.0-nougat, device-name

**How can I change the device name of an unrooted Android 7.0-based [Gigaset GS170 smartphone](http://www.gigaset.com/gigaset-gs170/) so it appears with a meaningful/readable name e.g. in a router's list of connected wifi devices?**

Various resources (e.g. [this](http://www.droidviews.com/how-change-phone-name-in-wifi-and-bluetooth-connection-on-samsung-galaxy-devices/) or [this](https://recomhub.com/blog/android-7-0-nougat-how-to-change-device-name-on-galaxy-s6-and-galaxy-s6-edge/)) suggest I should find a line saying *Device Name* in the *About Phone* section of the phone settings. However, I can see no such line there (images before and after scrolling down):

[image: About Phone screenshot]
[image: About Phone screenshot after scrolling down]

As the device is set to German, here are the translations of the items in their order of appearance:

- System Updates
- Status (Phone number, signal, etc.)
- Legal notes
- Model type number
- Android version
- State of security updates
- Baseband version
- Kernel version
- Build number
- Adapt creation version

**Is there somewhere else I could look for that option, or is it something only supported by specific devices?**

There are a few questions about this on this site (e.g. [this](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/37/how-do-i-change-the-name-of-my-android-device) and [this](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/66196/change-phone-name-on-nexus-4)), but those were posted several years ago, when early versions of Android with some "childhood diseases" (read: lack of basic features) were still the state of the art.

Comment: It would be under *About Devices*.  I don't know when this behaviour changed but on stock Marshmallow and Nougat you can't change it. If your device is rooted, you can use [this app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.developersinfo.android.dns.changer)

Comment: What is *Wi-Fi* device name?

Comment: @iBug: The name of the device in the local network it is connected to (e.g. in the router's list of connected wifi devices).

Comment: It was possible for me on my non-rooted stock COS13.1 on OnePlus One.

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK it's possible that a phone manufacturer hide that option from UI on their products, and I guess your phone it's one of them. My phone OnePlus 5, however, does allow changing it from Settings app.

So, if root access is available, try this in a rooted terminal environment:

```
setprop net.hostname "Whatever You Like"
```

Mount `/system` partition as R/W, head for `/system/build.prop`. Find this line and if it exists, change it (this line may not be present on Android 5 or lower):

```
ro.display.series=Same As Above
```

Reboot is required. After that the new name should have effect. Before modifying `build.prop` consider making a backup of it (and have a means of restore, e.g. via [recovery-mode](/questions/tagged/recovery-mode)): if the file is "broken", your device won't boot up properly.

Answer (score 1):

On my Android 7 phone (Zenfone 3) I was able to change the bluetooth name as follows:

1. Open "Settings"
2. Open "Bluetooth"
3. Select the action bar (the three dots in a vertical line in the top right of the display)
4. Select "Rename this device"
5. Enter the desired device name for bluetooth purposes
6. Select "Rename"

I was able to change the Wi-Fi name using a similar procedure:

1. Open "Settings"
2. Open "Wi-Fi"
3. Select the action bar (the three dots in a vertical line in the top right of the display)
4. Select "Rename this device"
5. Enter the desired device name for Wi-FI purposes
6. Select "Rename"

Comment: The "action bar" only has two options for me, "Update" (the list of wifis) and "Advanced", with the latter pointing to a menu for installing certificates, wifi direct, and WPS.