# What is my phone's hostname/network name?

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, networking

This should be really easy to find, but I've done a bunch of google searching and haven't found anything that works.  On Linux, you just type `hostname` and it tells you, but that doesn't work on my phone.

I know I've changed the hostname in the past (was `android-r` at one point), but I don't remember how.  All I want to do right now is see what it is, though, so I can connect to it without knowing the dynamic LAN IP address.

Comment: Related: [How do I change the name of my Android device?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/37)

Comment: @Firelord Ah, thanks.  The GUI method also works for me: http://android.stackexchange.com/a/61512/693

Comment: Interesting. Which device and Android version are you using? I don't have that option in Developer options. May be because I'm using an age-old Android version.

Comment: @Firelord It's specific to modded ROMs, just edited that into the answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a way to retrieve your device's hostname, but you'll have to meet one requirement, which is to have a Terminal Emulator installed on your device.

Once you have one, just open an instance of the emulator and issue the following command, followed by Enter:

```
getprop net.hostname
```

Your phone will then answer with its hostname.

Comment: This will give me an empty line as answer.
Typing in hostname gives me localhost.

Answer (score 2):

This depends on the device.
Some devices don't send their hostname to the router or that hostname is already used, so they are only reachable via their IP address or network local hostname (not device local hostname).

On Windows run `tracert <ip>` and you see the locally valid hostname of any device.

Example output:

```
1    94 ms     7 ms     9 ms  android-ce166eae64b93da4.fritz.box [192.168.178.24]´
```

So the hostname is `android-ce166eae64b93da4.fritz.box` for this specific network.
Usually the part in front of the network suffix (in this case `fritz.box`) is unique and works across networks (remember: only local).

Comment: yeah this didn't work for me, but I was hoping for something I could look at or run on the phone itself anyway

Comment: This worked correctly, as long as the IP address for the phone is known. This is extremely useful as my phone's IP changes a lot