# How can I know the hostname of an Android phone for use in SSH connection?

Tags: ssh, hosts

When setting up public key authentication on SimpleSSHD server on my Android phone, by http://www.galexander.org/software/simplesshd/

> Quick start
>
> - Install SimpleSSHD.
> - On any computer which will connect to your Android device, set the port to 2222.  With OpenSSH, this can be done by putting these lines in ~/.ssh/config:
>
>   ```
>   Host myphone
>   Port 2222
>   ```
> - Launch SimpleSSHD, and in Settings enable "Start on Boot", then manually start it for the first time.
> - Create `authorized_keys` in the home directory (do not use `ssh-copy-id`)
> - Optionally make .profile

how can I find out the hostname `myphone` for my android phone?

My phone is assigned different IP addresses from time to time. For example, I can move my laptop and phone to different LANs, and my phone can reconnect to the same LAN.

Some attempts from my laptop:

First attempt (fail):

```
$ ssh -p 2222 192.168.1.87
user@C6730:/data/data/org.galexander.sshd/files $ hostname
sh: hostname: not found
```

Second attempt (fail):

```
user@C6730:/data/data/org.galexander.sshd/files $ ^D
Connection to 192.168.1.87 closed.
t@ocean:/home/t$ ssh -p 2222 C6730
ssh: Could not resolve hostname c6730: No address associated with hostname
```

Third attempt (succeed with some luck by guessing):

I find all the hosts in the LAN by  `sudo nmap -sP 192.168.1.0/24`, and guess which host in the output is most likely the phone. it is something like `android-c0f659b6548c28b2` (not the real host name)

- Will `android-c0f659b6548c28b2` change under some cases, for example, when the phone is restarted, moved to a different LAN, assigned a different IP address, ...?
- Does anyone know what `c0f659b6548c28b2` means? It is not the Mac address of the phone.
- Can I customize the hostname of the Android phone?

Thanks.

Comment: A related question: [How to set friendly network name of android computer?](https://superuser.com/questions/408539/how-to-set-friendly-network-name-of-android-computer)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I change the name of my Android device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/37/how-do-i-change-the-name-of-my-android-device)

Comment: Related: [How to ping a local network host by hostname?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/215878/218526)